# T-SQL Newline String Concatenation For Exec()

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic

So, I've come across a pretty annoying problem with T-SQL... Essentially, in a table, there are several T-SQL statements. I want a stored procedure to efficiently grab these rows and concatenate them to a variable. Then, execute the concatenated lines with EXEC(@TSQL)

The problem is, string concatenation with newlines seem to be stripped when calling Exec...

For example something like:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''
select @sql += char(13) + char(10) + [sql] from [SqlTable]
exec(@sql) -- Won't always do the right thing
print @sql -- Looks good
```

I don't want to butcher the code with a Cursor, is there any way around this? Thanks!

Edit:
Okay, so it looks like the issue is in fact only with the GO statement, for example:

```
declare @test nvarchar(max) = 'create table #test4(i int) ' + char(10) + char(13) + 'GO' + char(10) + char(13) +'create table #test5(i int)'
exec(@test)
```

I guess this go will have to go (no pun intended) I just really didn't want to have to try and parse it in fear of special cases blowing up the whole thing.

Comment: Can you separate the statements with a semi-colon, rather than newlines?

Comment: I don't think so, some of the SQL contains various syntax (including GO statements) which cannot be converted into "create table [A](i int);GO;"

Comment: Is it terminating at the point of the first `GO`?

Comment: It would help if you posted some example data, the resulting SQL, and what you'd like the resulting SQL to be

Comment: Yes shawnt00, there is a syntax error after the GO "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'create'."

Comment: I think that `EXEC` treats the entire string as a single batch. `GO` is not really a TSQL command hence the syntax error.

Comment: That's right. GO is not SQL. It is a pre-processor directive in SQL Management Studio. If you are parsing your code for exec, use a separate exec for each GO and eliminate the GO's altogether.

The good news is that GO has to be on its own line for SSMS to recognize it, so parsing it is easy. (This is exactly what I do with my SQL to EXEC parser I use for database code versioning.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `select` statement without `order by` is free to return results in any order.

You'd have to specify the order in which your SQL snippets make sense:

```
select  @sql += char(13) + char(10) + [sql] 
from    [SqlTable]
order by
        SnippetSequenceNr
```

As @Bort suggested in the comments, if the snippets are stand-alone SQL, you can separate them with a semicolon.  Carriage returns, newlines, tabs and spaces are all the same in T-SQL: they're whitespace.

```
select  @sql += [sql] + ';'
from    [SqlTable]
order by
        SnippetSequenceNr
```

Comment: @BobTodd Then you must never have use `WITH`. It's a habit you should start.

Comment: Regardless of your thoughts on `WITH`, it's going to be required syntax very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the `GO` "statements". As noted by others you also might need to ensure the string is constructing in the correct statement sequence. Using `+=` is probably not the best idea, though I'm not sure about the dynamic sql idea in the first place. It might actually be more appropriate to use a cursor here.

Answer (score 0):

Sam F,

Your method didn't work with FOR XML method of string concatenation (if you wanted to create a "line" delimited list, based on values found in different rows of a table). However, replace the char(13) with SPACE(13), then it works great.

```
SELECT PackageNote = SUBSTRING((SELECT (SPACE(13) + char(10) + PackageDescription)
FROM POPackageNote PN2
WHERE PN1.PurchaseOrderNumber = PN2.PurchaseOrderNumber
ORDER BY POPackageNoteID, PackageDescription
    FOR XML PATH( '' ) 
    ), 3, 1000 )
FROM POPackageNote PN1
WHERE (PurchaseOrderNumber = @PurchaseOrderNumber)
GROUP BY PurchaseOrderNumber
```